# C# DynamoDB QueryAsync result not properly displaying (Update: Fixed)

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, .net-4.8

I feel I'm making a very elementary mistake. Its my first time using C# with DynamoDB so everything is very new. The question I want to ask is how do I display the result. I tried saving it in a file, but all I get is 
`System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[ConnectDB.Tables.Reply]]` 
Also I'm having to convert it to string first. If I don't it says 

`CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConnectDB.Tables.Reply>>' to 'string'`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Reply>> Get(string Id = "001")
{
         AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsAccessKeyId: "ihgowijrlejsafjaklsjgo", awsSecretAccessKey: "hiowajflekahglajsgaijkgilw", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.ap-east-1);
         DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(client);

         return await context.QueryAsync<Reply>(Id).GetRemainingAsync();
}
```

## Update: Fixed

This is how I fixed it. I was displaying it wrong, thanks [Ermiya Eskandary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800344/ermiya-eskandary).

```
public Getitems new_obj = new Getitems();
protected async void buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string path = @"file.json";
        StreamWriter OurStream;
        OurStream = File.CreateText(path);
        var results = await new_obj.Get();
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(results, options);
        OurStream.WriteLine(jsonString);     
        OurStream.Close();

}
```

Comment: How are you calling `Get`? And are you trying to just display this? Is console output acceptable? Your code looks fine as long as you do `var results = await Get(...);` and then you'll have an `IEnumerable<Reply>`. You can then loop over this and display it or loop over it & serialise it to JSON to then write to a file. Recommended reading: [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to). We need to see the code which you've written for writing this to a file to help you more.

Comment: Yes...I guess you are missing await in your calling method.

Comment: Thanks Ermiya Eskandary. You were right, I managed to fix it thanks to you. I will add the code to the question as an update. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. You as well Ankush Jain.